# Running php from cron did not run as CLI

Tags: php, cron

I noticed this problem after a php script ran from cron started to timeout but it was not an issue when it was ran manually from command line. (PHP has max_execution_time is 0 for CLI by default)

So I tried to run a simple cron such:

```
50 8 * * * php -q /tmp/phpinfo.php > /tmp/phpinfo
```

The script would just call phpinfo().

Surprisingly it wrote out phpinfo in html format, which suggested that it was not run as CLI. And max_execution_time was 30 in the output.

Running the script manually from command line such

```
php -q /tmp/phpinfo.php | less
```

wrote out the php info in text format and max_execution_time was 0 in the output.

I know there must be a configuration issue somewhere, but I just could not find where the problem is. This is happening on a production server, which I have a complete control of. Running the same script from cron on my development machine worked fine.

Here is the summary of the difference

```
function             | CLI                     | cron                   |
php_sapi_name        | cli                     | cgi-fcgi               |
php_ini_loaded_file  | /usr/local/lib/php.ini  | /usr/local/lib/php.ini |
```

Comment: To confirm if it is actually in CLI mode, try echoing out [`php_sapi_name()`](http://php.net/function.php-sapi-name.php). You could also check what `php.ini` is being included with [`php_ini_loaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-ini-loaded-file.php) and [`php_ini_scanned_files`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-ini-scanned-files.php). The most common cause of discrepancies of this sort is that you have some "environment variables" set for your normal shell which will not be set when cron runs.

Comment: No that is incorrect. This is from the phpinfo docu page "Note: phpinfo() outputs plain text instead of HTML when using the CLI mode."

Comment: Get rid of the `-q` flag. You don't need it, and it could even be the cause of this problem.

Comment: -q was not the problem. That is for a quiet mode and yes I've tried removing this.

Comment: I was interested to find out what the other differences might be between running cli and cgi-fcgi from shell. Here is a list from php.net: http://us.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.differences.php

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I suspect your problem lies in a missing environment variable, specifically the all-important `$PATH`. When you run this:

```
php -q /tmp/phpinfo.php
```

the system must work out what program you mean by `php`. It does this by looking, in order, through the directories in the current `$PATH` environment variable.

Executed from a normal shell, your environment is set up in such a way that it finds the CLI version of PHP, as you expect.

However, when `cron` executes a command, it does so without all the environment variables that your interactive shell would set up. Since there will probably be other executables called `php` on your system, for different "SAPIs", it may pick the "wrong" one - in your case, the `cgi-fcgi` executable, according to the output you report from `php_sapi_name()`.

To fix this, first find the path to the correct `php` executable in a normal shell by typing this:

```
which php
```

This should give you a path like `/usr/bin/php`. You can go one further and check if this is actually a "symbolic link" pointing at a different filename:

```
ls -l $(which php)
```

(you'll see an arrow in the output if it is, like `/usr/bin/php -> /usr/bin/php5-cli`)

Then take this full path to the PHP executable and use that in your crontab entry, so it looks something like this:

```
50 8 * * * /usr/bin/php5-cli -q /tmp/phpinfo.php > /tmp/phpinfo
```

Comment: That was exactly the problem. Thanks for your suggestion. I ended up adding the following on the top of cron so that I dont need to change the command. PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

Comment: This works for me too, changed "php" to "/usr/local/bin/php", my output from "which php" and it's running as a CLI from cron now.

Comment: Great info, thanks that helped much!

Although it didn't help in the end with my problem, why CRON PHP runs without proper mask S_IFCHR and instead it presents (STDIN) as S_IFIFO.