# calling /usr/bin/php from cpanel crontab always gives instead of cgi-fcgi

Tags: php, ssh, cron

i'm using this `/usr/bin/php -q /home/user/public_html/cron.php`
and i the front of the cron.php file `var_dump(PHP_SAPI);`
it gives me `cgi-fcgi` when i calling from http and when it called from ssh crontab too

i saw this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19917512/1377781
and i changed the cron command to `/usr/bin/php5-cli  -q /home/user/public_html/cron.php`

and its worked fine, is that right? is it will work on all hosts? and environments?

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily, no.

There is no guarantee that every host or environment has the identical binary path and name for PHP. Just like I could rename `MSWord.exe` to `foobar.exe` on a Windows system, I can rename my PHP binary to `foobar` on a *nix system, all the same.

*Usually* (but not always) your binary files are stored in `/usr/bin` and `/usr/local/bin` on a *nix system. So you can look in there (something like `ls -lah /usr/bin/php*` or `ls -lah /usr/local/bin/php*`) and check each binary with `/path/to/binary/<binary name> -v`.

For example, on my local setup I have 20 different PHP binaries for 5 different SAPIs in `/usr/bin` and a few more in `/usr/local/bin` and some more in `/etc/php`.

```
sherif@sdev:~$ ls /usr/bin/php*

/usr/bin/php -> /etc/alternatives/php
/usr/bin/phpize -> /etc/alternatives/phpize
/usr/bin/phpize55
/usr/bin/php55-mod -> /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp55.so
/usr/bin/php55-fpm
/usr/bin/php55-cli
/usr/bin/php55-cgi
/usr/bin/php55dbg
/usr/bin/phpize56
/usr/bin/php56-mod -> /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp56.so
/usr/bin/php56-fpm
/usr/bin/php56-cli
/usr/bin/php56-cgi
/usr/bin/php56dbg
/usr/bin/phpize7
/usr/bin/php7-mod -> /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.so
/usr/bin/php7-fpm
/usr/bin/php7-cli
/usr/bin/php7-cgi
/usr/bin/php7dbg
/usr/bin/phpize71
/usr/bin/php71-mod -> /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp71.so
/usr/bin/php71-fpm
/usr/bin/php71-cli
/usr/bin/php71-cgi
/usr/bin/php71dbg
```

So two things to look out for.

1. When not specifying the absolute path to the executable, you have to take into account the `$PATH` environment variable (this can change from user to user).
2. When you are specifying the absolute path, make sure you check if it's the executable you want first. Don't just blindly assume it is based on convention. It might not be the same on every system.